# How to change attribute of dynamically added element on just calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change attribute of dynamically added element on just calling a function, not on changing attribute by binding an event to it.

**What My Code does:**
I'm trying to load all previous content on browser back button through jquery.
I need to update all the loadmore button(which is dynamically created) with new href attribute depending upon the url present in browser and checked option on the sidebar form.

**Problem:**
The problem is that I unable to update the href attribute of dynamically added element.

**What I have tried**

The `botSpace` is a fixed class and dynamically added element has `sidebar_loadMore` class.

Dynamically Added element

```
<a id="loadMore" class="sidebar_loadMore" onclick="more_leftajaxsearchcategory(0,0,this);" href="#apiscroll=1">View More</a>
```

I'm trying to update the href as the url as the value.

```
jQuery('.botSpace').find('.sidebar_loadMore').attr('href', scroll);
```

.

```
jQuery("body").on("ready",'.sidebar_loadMore',function(){   
    jQuery(this).attr('href', scroll);
})
```

Also I have tried to bind the `mouseenter` event. This works but causes problem in some other cases.
And tried to bind some custom event but failed to implement it.

**Live URL:** You can check the code here [Bestofthebrunch](http://bestofthebrunch.co.uk/dev/search-listing)

Comment: use `prop` instead of `attr`.

Comment: @Mouser `attr` works fine if the elements are static.

Comment: Instead of a link, provide us with some relevant HTML.

Comment: Please add it to your question.

Comment: You need to catch the moment when the element is added to the DOM. You can't change attributes to elements that don't exist.

Comment: Element is added to the DOM when checkboxes are clicked

Comment: Do you control those checkboxes? If so, put a click event on them. Everytime the checkbox is clicked, run the code that changes the links.

Comment: A function is called when check boxes are clicked. I have the control of the function. But currently the problem occurs when we press back button of browser.

Comment: Please delete this question, repost it with the complete information to get an answer that helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Mouser's got a point, it is pretty hard to work out what you're trying to do and what's going wrong. I've had a look at your link - it's not returning any search results and I cannot see the 'loadmore' button. Mouser is referring to the idea of a 'MCVE' - see here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ... this is usually done via an embedded code fragment or a jsfiddle, but it could be done via your linked dev site. But at the moment I am struggling to verify the problem. Could you list a step-by-step process to replicate the problem on your site?

Comment: @Mouser Thanks for your suggestion. I updated the URL from where it is added to DOM dynamically, and changed my code to satisfy my all condition. After 1 hour of work finally got the solution. Thanks once again.

Comment: nice one, well done! In that case, would you mind either answering the quesiton yourself (and it is OK to mark your own answer as accepted) or delete the question? This is so that there isn't an unanswered question floating about on SO... the goal is to work every question towards an accepted answer, or eventually close it! I think if it stays unanswered and unvoted, it will get automatically closed anyway, at some point.

Comment: (found it - useful link that explains all this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a condition to check whether a browsers back button is pressed by simply calling a function `leftajaxsearchcategory(value1, value2, back=true)`. This is the function which adds the load more element in the DOM. And on the called function side checked for a condition if url has a hash value and back is true then I update the href according my need like this...

```
if(window.location.hash && back){
    var scroll = getScroll();
    var scrollURL = getScrollURL(scroll);
    var url = '<a id="loadMore" class="sidebar_loadMore"  onclick="more_leftajaxsearchcategory(0,0,this);" href="'+scrollURL+'">View More</a>';                 
}
else if(!back){
    var url = '<a id="loadMore" class="sidebar_loadMore"  onclick="more_leftajaxsearchcategory(0,0,this);" href="#apiscroll=1">View More</a>';  
}
```

and finally problem resolved. 
Thanks to all for suggesting me the possible way to solve my problem.